# Generating a unique key for a React dynamically addable / removable component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working on a React component that the user can dynamically add / remove children (kind of like a todo-list style).

The challenge is that the user can click a button to add in / remove children and, so, any new child may not have anything unique about it to set as the key element (aside from, maybe, the creation time) and, since, the user can delete any one of these component and, then, re-add more, the index won't work.

Here's what I've come up with that seems to work:

```
class ParentComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            data: [ XXXX ]
        };
    }
    
    addSection(title, content, key = this.generateNewKeyVal()) {
    this.setState({
        data: 
        [...this.state.data, 
            {
            title: title, 
            content: content,
            key: key
            }
        ]
    });
    }

    generateNewKeyVal() {
    if(this.state.data.length === 0)
        return 1;

    return Math.max.apply(Math, this.state.data.map(d => d.key)) + 1;
    }

    removeFunc(key) {
        this.setState({
        data: this.state.data.filter(e1 => e1.key !== key)
        });
    }

}

export default ParentComponent;
```

As I said, my `generateNewKeyVal()` function seems to work perfectly since it ensures it generates a new, unique integer value for `key` (based upon the values currently in the array, that is) and, so long as that `key` remains in the array, the function will ensure a higher number will be created for a new item's `key`.

My challenge is that I'm SO new to React that I'd like to make sure I'm not making some huge mistake here or if there is a better way to generate a key in this kind of situation.

Comment: `generateNewKeyVal` will fail if you use this component twice on the same page. Best practices here is to actually use a global variable you add to `window` (unless you SSR) and increment from there.

Comment: @Dominik, I understood that React only requires a unique key among siblings. That should make sure this is safe since this references the parent array, no?

Comment: Sorry I don't actually understand what you're using that unique key for. I'm just saying if you want a truly unique key, like for an ID in HTML then this might break.

Comment: If you're using the key just for iterating over react children that you generate than this is over complicated and could be made more simple